# Use FFMPEG to combine different MP4s with srt into one file

Tags: ffmpeg

So...probably a very basic question for those of you familiar with FFMPEG (I'm really not). I know that you can combine multiple videos into one using FFMPEG, but what about if each video has its own srt file, saved separately in a 'subs' folder and NOT included in the video itself?

Is it possible for FFMPEG to also combine the srt files into a single one (and recalculate the timestamps), and then merge this into the final, combined video? If so, what would the command be?

For example, I have video1.mp4 and video2.mp4. They have corresponding sub1.srt and sub2.srt. When video1.mp4 and video2.mp4 are merged, the timestamps for sub2.srt will, of course, be out of sync now and need to be corrected by adding the duration of video1.mp4 to the individual timestamps (i.e., if video1 is 30 seconds long, and the first subtitle in sub2.srt appears at the 2-second mark, then after the combination, it should now appear at the (30+2)=32-second mark, and so on.

If it helps, all the files are mp4, and have the same dimensions (720p).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856623 asks the same thing, unfortunately also without an answer.

Comment: Have you tried merging video+srt pairs first, and then concatenating these resulting container files into a new one?

Comment: The `-itsoffset offset (input)` parameter sounds promising…

Answer (score 3):

While there might be a (complicated) way to concatenate the srt files first, the easiest way is to combine pairs of video and text first, and then concatenate the resulting container files.

1. Copy everything from video1.mp4 and add subtitles from sub1.srt

```sh
# Assuming English for subtitle language
ffmpeg -i video1.mp4 -i sub1.srt -c copy -c:s mov_text -metadata:s:s:0 language=en -metadata:s:s:0 title=English 1.mp4
```

`-c copy` will copy everything that might be in video1.mp4, and `-c:s mov_text` will format the text stream from sub1.srt into subtitles for mp4 (mov_text). The result will be written to *1.mp4*.

2. Repeat the same command for all the other video-subtitles pairs.
3. Create a text file (f.e. chapters.txt) with the resulting file names

```
file 1.mp4
file 2.mp4
file 3.mp4
…
```

4. Concatenate the resulting container files listed in the text file

```sh
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i chapters.txt -c copy everything.mp4
```

See [ffmpeg's concatenate demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#demuxer)

There are other ffmpeg commands that can also deal with different dimensions, mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason I had to explicitly copy the video, audio, and subtitle streams individually on step 4, otherwise I ended up with silent videos. So my step 4 looked like this:

ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i chapter.txt -c:v copy -c:a copy -c:s copy everything.mp4